# querying mongodb in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

This is how a typical document in my collection is structured:

```
{u'_id': ObjectId('58645996fa36ac0b9f0e738d'),
 u'alias': u'loco_ono',
 u'artist': u'ONO’,
 u'date_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 29, 0, 32, 22, 723000),
 u'followers': [{u'permalink': u'pschedelicsuperfuzz',
   u'plan': u'Free'},
  {u'permalink': u'd-miller',
   u'plan': u'Free'}],
 u'followers_count': 60,
 u'last_modified': u'2016/10/17 18:53:09 +0000',
 u'plan': u'Pro'}
```

How can I iterate through every document in my collection and write to a CSV file the following information for each iteration using pymongo?

```
Artist   | Follower               | Count
loco_ono | pschedelicsuperfuzz    | 1
loco_ono | d-miller               | 1
```

So far I have this:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_client = MongoClient()
db = mongo_client.soundcloud_db
artist_followers = db.artist_followers
```

I'm not sure how to iterate through the artist_followers collection correctly and retrieve only the 'permalink' field values from the 'followers' array for each artist to output in the format described above.

Comment: What you tried `for item in artist_followers: print item` yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to iterate over `collection.find()` to retrieve the documents from the collections, then use an inner loop to iterate over the followers.

I don't understand your count field, and the exact formatting will take a bit of fiddling, but here's a fragment that should help you:

```
for doc in artist_followers.find():
    for follower in doc["followers"]:
        print(doc["alias"], follower["permalink"])
```